# Add my app to HTC cut & paste sendto menu

Tags: android, android-intent

my HTC has a nice cut & paste function that allows me to mark text with two green sliders and then perform either a search on it, push the text to the clipboard or send it to an app.

The apps shown in the menu are: Friend Stream, Mail, Nachricht (SMS message), Peep (all HTC)

I want to have my app appear here - but don't know how.

My app is listed on other send menues (e.g. send link to, send image) but I cannot get on the cut & paste menu.

Anyone out there who knows more?

/Paul

Comment: Sounds like this is related to intents. I tagged it as such. Retag if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the logcat for ActivityManager.  You should see a line that looks something like the following when you select one of the options like "Friend Stream".

`I/ActivityManager(   54): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/.Launcher }`
(This is what gets output when the HOME key is hit)

You'll need to add an intent filter that matches all of the various parameters(action, categories, data, etc.) on the intent that is getting sent and then your application should also show up.

This seems to be something HTC specific as I can't find it on a non-HTC device otherwise I would try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

you tip was really helpfull! This is what I captured:

09-09 08:07:19.477: INFO/ActivityManager(79): Starting activity: Intent { act=share typ=text/plain flg=0x13000000 cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity (has extras) }

First I didn't understand the action as it was not a standard android action such as
act=android.intent.action.SEND

But I tried it out:

An oddly enough it works!

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

/Paul